# How do I get the last part of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have many strings that follow the same convention:

```
this.is.a.sample
this.is.another.sample.of.it
this.too
```

What i want to do is isolate the last part.  So i want "sample", or "it", or "too".

What is the most efficient way for this to happen.  Obviously there are many ways to do this, but which way is best that uses the least resources (CPU and RAM).

Comment: [strrchr](http://php.net/strrchr) is a good starting point.  Also [substr](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: i know how to do this, but i want the most efficient way for this to happen a lot of times relatively quickly.

Comment: Wouldn't that have been a good qualifier to put into the question itself‽

Comment: Better answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17030851/1022579

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$string = "this.is.another.sample.of.it";
$contents = explode('.', $string);

echo end($contents); // displays 'it'
```

Comment: Is this actually faster than using strrchr && strrpos?
substr($string, strrchr($string, '.')+1)

Comment: It seems to be the case: [What is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826797/php-listexplode-vs-substrstrpos-what-is-more-efficient). Tests were done with PHP5 though.

Answer (score 7):

I realise this question is from 2012, but the answers here are all inefficient.  There are string functions built into PHP to do this, rather than having to traverse the string and turn it into an array, and then pick the last index, which is a lot of work to do something quite simple.

The following code gets the last occurrence of a string within a string:

```
strrchr($string, '.'); // Last occurrence of '.' within a string
```

We can use this in conjunction with `substr`, which essentially chops a string up based on a position.

```
$string = 'this.is.a.sample';
$last_section = substr($string, (strrchr($string, '-') + 1));
echo $last_section; // 'sample'
```

Note the `+1` on the `strrchr` result; this is because `strrchr` returns the index of the string within the string (starting at position 0), so the true 'position' is always 1 character on.

Comment: This is good advice, though there's a small issue in your actual code. strrchr returns the portion of the string after and including the given char, not a numeric index. So you would want to do $last_section = substr(strrchr($string, '.'), 1); to get everything after the char.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/strpos

```
$haystack = "this.is.another.sample.of.it"; 
$needle = "sample"; 
$string = substr( $haystack, strpos( $haystack, $needle ), strlen( $needle ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
$string = "this.is.another.sample.of.it";
$parts = explode('.', $string);
$last = array_pop(parts);
```

Comment: This is not recommended: `PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference.`

Comment: So @Daniel-KM just break the function in 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_string = explode(".", "this.is.sparta");
$last_part = $new_string[count($new_string)-1];

echo $last_part;    // prints "sparta".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "this.is.another.sample.of.it";
$result = explode('.', $string); // using explode function

print_r($result); // whole Array
```

Will give you

```
result[0]=>this;
result[1]=>is;
result[2]=>another;
result[3]=>sample;
result[4]=>of;
result[5]=>it;
```

Display any one you want (ex. `echo result[5];`)