# Splitting strings in PHP and get the last part

Tags: php, string

I need to split a string in PHP by "-" and get the last part.

So from this:

> abc-123-xyz-789

I expect to get

> "789"

This is the code I've come up with:

```
substr(strrchr($urlId, '-'), 1)
```

which works fine, except:

If my input string does not contain any "-", I must get the whole string, like from:

> 123

I need to get back

> 123

and it needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: `explode()`, `end()`.

Comment: `end(split('-',$str))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24465512/2943403

Answer (score 155, accepted):

- `preg_split($pattern,$string)` split strings within a given regex pattern
- `explode($pattern,$string)` split strings within a given pattern
- `end($arr)` get last array element

So:

```
$strArray = explode('-',$str)
$lastElement = end(explode('-', $strArray));
// or
$lastElement = end(preg_split('/-/', $str));
```

Will return the last element of a `-` separated string.

---

And there's a hardcore way to do this:

```
$str = '1-2-3-4-5';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '-') + 1);
//      |            '--- get the last position of '-' and add 1(if don't substr will get '-' too)
//      '----- get the last piece of string after the last occurrence of '-'
```

Comment: Do you know if using end() is quicker then array_pop or what is the difference?

Comment: `array_pop` will remove last element from array and return the last element, `end` just return the last element. I think there's no performance difference.

Comment: @Skarlinski Simply _not_ exploding if not necessary would sensibly be the quickest.

Comment: I added a hardcore way too :P

Comment: isn't "split" deprecated"?

Comment: Updated answer with all possible(and right) ways to do. I was researching and `explode` is(theorical) faster than `split`.

Comment: `end(explode('-',$str))` gives this error: `Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference`. This solves: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference

Comment: @trante According to docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php#refsect1-function.end-parameters
the result of a function cannot be passed into `end()`

Comment: Really handy to split breadcrumbs and as you said, it's hardcore and fast.

Comment: Note that 'split' was removed in 7.0 PHP version.

Answer (score 30):

```
$string = 'abc-123-xyz-789';
$exploded = explode('-', $string);
echo end($exploded);
```

This does not have the E_STRICT issue.

Comment: It causes E_STRICT: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 7):

Just check whether or not the delimiting character exists, and either split or don't:

```
if (strpos($potentiallyDelimitedString, '-') !== FALSE) {
  found delimiter, so split
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
array_reverse(explode('-', $str))[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

To satisfy the requirement that *"it needs to be as fast as possible"* I ran a benchmark against some possible solutions. Each solution had to satisfy this set of test cases.

```
$cases = [
    'aaa-zzz'                     => 'zzz',
    'zzz'                         => 'zzz',
    '-zzz'                        => 'zzz',
    'aaa-'                        => '',
    ''                            => '',
    'aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff-zzz' => 'zzz',
];
```

Here are the solutions:

```
function test_substr($str, $delimiter = '-') {
    $idx = strrpos($str, $delimiter);
    return $idx === false ? $str : substr($str, $idx + 1);
}

function test_end_index($str, $delimiter = '-') {
    $arr = explode($delimiter, $str);
    return $arr[count($arr) - 1];
}

function test_end_explode($str, $delimiter = '-') {
    $arr = explode($delimiter, $str);
    return end($arr);
}

function test_end_preg_split($str, $pattern = '/-/') {
    $arr = preg_split($pattern, $str);
    return end($arr);
}
```

Here are the results after each solution was run against the test cases 1,000,000 times:

```
test_substr               : 1.706 sec
test_end_index            : 2.131 sec  +0.425 sec  +25%
test_end_explode          : 2.199 sec  +0.493 sec  +29%
test_end_preg_split       : 2.775 sec  +1.069 sec  +63%
```

So turns out the fastest of these was using `substr` with `strpos`. Note that in this solution we must check `strpos` for `false` so we can return the full string (catering for the `zzz` case).

Answer (score 3):

This code will do that

```
<?php
$string = 'abc-123-xyz-789';
$output = explode("-",$string);
echo $output[count($output)-1];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016338/55075):

```
end((explode('-', $string)));
```

which won't cause an *E_STRICT* warning in PHP 5 ([PHP magic](http://phpsadness.com/sad/51)). Although [the warning will be issued in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.parentheses), so adding `@` in front of it can be used as a workaround.

Comment: ..and magic si gone with `php7` http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.parentheses

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned by others, if you don't assign the result of `explode()` to a variable, you get the message:

> E_STRICT: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

The correct way is:

```
$words = explode('-', 'hello-world-123');
$id = array_pop($words); // 123
$slug = implode('-', $words); // hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `explode()` returns an array, you can add square brackets directly to the end of that function, if you happen to know the position of the last array item.

```
$email = 'name@example.com';
$provider = explode('@', $email)[1];
echo $provider; // example.com
```

Or another way is `list()`:

```
$email = 'name@example.com';
list($prefix, $provider) = explode('@', $email);
echo $provider; // example.com
```

If you don't know the position:

```
$path = 'one/two/three/four';
$dirs = explode('/', $path);
$last_dir = $dirs[count($dirs) - 1];
echo $last_dir; // four
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has a bug in it where it still eats the first character of the input string if the delimiter is not found.

```
$str = '1-2-3-4-5';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '-') + 1);
```

Produces the expected result: `5`

```
$str = '1-2-3-4-5';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, ';') + 1);
```

Produces `-2-3-4-5`

```
$str = '1-2-3-4-5';
if (($pos = strrpos($str, ';')) !== false)
    echo substr($str, $pos + 1);
else
    echo $str;
```

Produces the whole string as desired.

[3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/Ihtf2)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is null-safe and supports all PHP versions:

```
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
$strLastStringToken = array_slice(explode('-',$str),-1,1)[0];
```

returning `''` if `$str = null`.

Answer (score 0):

The hardcore way for me:

```
  $last = explode('-',$urlId)[count(explode('-',$urlId))-1];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
$str = "abc-123-xyz-789";
$last = array_pop( explode('-', $str) );
echo $last; //echoes 789
```

Comment: It causes E_STRICT: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: I don't know why people think this answer is not useful. It's work for me, thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use **array_pop** combined with **explode**

Code:

```
$string = 'abc-123-xyz-789';
$output = array_pop(explode("-",$string));
echo $output;
```

**DEMO**: [Click here](http://codepad.org/re1VGntA)

Comment: It causes E_STRICT: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
$str = "abc-123-xyz-789";
$arr = explode('-', $str);
$last = array_pop( $arr );
echo $last; //echoes 789
```

Comment: this is practically a duplicate anwer, but also on a post of over 5 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Just call the following single line of code:

```
 $expectedString = end(explode('-', $orignalString));
```

Comment: This leads to an error as detailed in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference).

Comment: oh, use `'-'` as saperator, where as I used `'/'`. Anyway, I corrected my code. Please check it now.