# How can i Select Everything In Url except filename and extension?

Tags: python, regex, find

```
https://fire.vimeocdn.com/1485599447-0xf546ac1afe7bce06fa5153973a8b85b1c45051d3/159463108/video/499604330/playlist.m3u8
```

I want to **Include Everything Except** `playlist.m3u8`

```
(playlist.[^.]*)
```

is selecting "playlist.m3u8", i need to do exactly opposite.

Here is an Demo. https://regex101.com/r/RONA65/1

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465512/regular-expression-to-match-everything-until-the-last-occurrence-of would be helpful.

Comment: @Nowhere Check my solution. I think you were looking for positive look ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead:

```
(.*)(?=playlist\.[^.]*)
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/RONA65/4

---

Or you can try it like this as well:

```
.*\/
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/RONA65/2

Regex:

`.*\/` Select everything till last `/`

Comment: Second Approach is Good, select all till /, Winner

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function:

```
>>> s = 'https://fire.vimeocdn.com/.../159463108/video/499604330/playlist.m3u8'
>>> '/'.join(s.split('/')[:-1])
'https://fire.vimeocdn.com/.../159463108/video/499604330'
```

Or simpler with rsplit:

```
>>> s = 'https://fire.vimeocdn.com/.../159463108/video/499604330/playlist.m3u8'
>>> s.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
'https://fire.vimeocdn.com/.../159463108/video/499604330'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **non-greedy** match by adding '?' after '*'

```
import re
s = 'https://fire.vimeocdn.com/1485599447-0xf546ac1afe7bce06fa5153973a8b85b1c45051d3/159463108/video/499604330/playlist.m3u8'
m = re.match('(.*?)(playlist.[^.]*)', s)
print(m.group(1))
```