# Regex: Everything until last occurrence of pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, path

Given the following strings:

```
'/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/g'
'/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/'
'/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f'
'/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/g/xxx/xxx'
```

I'm looking for a regex that will match

```
/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f
```

for all of the above strings

That is, match ***everything until the last occurrence of this pattern:***

***{forward slash or start of string} then {xxx} then {forward slash} then {any group of chars (except forward slash) that is not equal to xxx } then {forward slash or end of string}***

I do not know how to translate the above pattern into a regex.

The `.*\/` pattern I tried does not solve the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your always good regexs. I think this isn't a dupplicate of what you linked, because that answers include the /.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nevermind, OP edited question and fully changed it.

Comment: @SproutCoder What is the code/pattern that does not work for you? Your current title and *match everything until the last occurrence of this pattern* requirement is in line with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465512/regular-expression-to-match-everything-until-the-last-occurrence-of). Please update the question if that solution does not work for you.

Comment: @SproutCoder I don't understand your edit. Why does /a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f match entirely and not /a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx since the last /whatever shouldn't be included? And where is the g for the last supposed good match? Shouldn't it just remove the /xxx.. part? In fact shouldn't it remove only the last /xxx?

Comment: So, https://regex101.com/r/UYvZDh/6 works as expected,right?

Comment: yes it looks like this is the correct answer, I can't think of any other edge cases, it looks like this is following the exact pattern I mentioned

Comment: Ok, note that `{anything but xxx}` is not clear in the question, it can be understood as `(?:(?!xxx).)*` to match any char, 0+ times, that does not start `xxx` sequence. And what you need is `{any subpart not equal to xxx}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?:.*\/)?xxx\/(?!xxx(?![^\/]))[^/]*(?=$|\/)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYvZDh/6).

**Details**

- `(?:.*\/)?` - an optional group matching

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\/` - a `/` char
- `xxx\/` - a `xxx/` substring
- `(?!xxx(?![^\/]))` - the text starting at the next location in string cannot be equal to `xxx/` or `xxx` at the end of the string
- `[^/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/` as many as possible (`[^/]*`)
- `(?=$|\/)` - there must be end of string or `/` immediately to the right of the current position.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/g','/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/','/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f','/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/xxx/f/g/xxx/xxx','/xxx/f/g','xxx/f/g','a/xxx/f/g','/a/xxx/f/g','/a/xxx/b/c/xxx/xxx/d/e/xxx/gggxxxd/f/gxxxf/'];
var rx = /(?:.*\/)?xxx\/(?!xxx(?![^\/]))[^/]*(?=$|\/)/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.match(rx)[0]);
}
```