# How to get String Before Last occurrence of substring?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to get String before last occurrence of my given sub string.

My String was,

> path =
>   D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v1001-1010.mov

my substring, `1001-1010` which will occurred twice. all i want is get string before its last occurrence.

**Note:** My substring is dynamic with different padding but only number.

I want,

> D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v

I have done using regex and slicing,

```
>>> p = 'D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v1001-1010.mov'
>>> q = re.findall("\d*-\d*",p)
>>> q[-1].join(p.split(q[-1])[:-1])
'D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v'
>>>
```

Is their any better way to do by purely using regex?

**Please Note I have tried so many eg:**

1. [regular expression to match everything until the last occurrence of /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465512/regular-expression-to-match-everything-until-the-last-occurrence-of)
2. [Regex Last occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence)

I got answer by using regex with slicing but i want to achieve by using regex alone..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple greedy match and a capture group:

```
(.*)1001-1010
```

Your match is in capture group #1

Since `.*` is greedy by nature, it will match **longest match** before matching your keyword `1001-1010`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQSHFy/2)

---

As per comments below if keyword is not a static string then you may use this regex:

```
r'(.*\D)\d+-\d+'
```

**Python Code:**

```
>>> p = 'D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v1001-1010.mov'
>>> print (re.findall(r'(.*\D)\d+-\d+', p))
['D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v']
```

Comment: great i have slightly modified your answer.. `(.*)\d*-\d*` number also not static so i made it like this.. padding will differ .. thanks i have tried .*(\d*-\d*)\/ instead. thats why i didnt found

Comment: Yes you may also use: `r'(.*\D)\d+-\d+'`

Comment: thanks @anubhava (.*\D)\d+-\d+  this is what i want.. previous one gave me string along with substring but this has both.

Comment: ok answer updated accordingly. Please mention this in your question as well so readers would better understand why a regex approach is needed and string search using `rfind` won't work.

Comment: accepted +1 rfind can be useful for static but mine is dynamic.. thats i found my solution

Answer (score 8):

Why use `regex`. Just use built in string methods:

```
path = "D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v1001-1010.mov"
index = path.rfind("1001-1010")
print(path[:index])
```

Comment: looks good.. nice example without regex.. but problem is i dont know substring.. substring will be some number with padding..

Comment: Yes this approach will work only with a static pattern but if keyword is unknown and a pattern search is required then regex is must.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @anubhava,

My first regex was,

```
.*(\d*-\d*)\/
```

Now i have corrected mine..

```
.*(\d*-\d*)
```

or

```
(.*)(\d*-\d*)
```

which gives me,

```
>>> q = re.search('.+(\d*-\d*)', p)
>>> q.group()
'D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v0001-1001'
>>> 

(.*\D)\d+-\d+
```

this gives me exactly what i want...

```
>>> q = re.search('(.*\D)\d+-\d+', p)
>>> q.groups()
('D:/me/vol101/Prod/cent/2019_04_23_01/image/AVEN_000_3400_img_pic_p1001-1010/pxy/AVEN_000_3400_img-mp4_to_MOV_v',)
>>>
```