# String spliting in a word (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, split

I split a string until the first four characters into an array with this code:

```
$word = "google";    
substr($word, 0, 4);
```

But now I want to get the rest of the string into another array.

Ex: here I want to get "le" into another array. Is there a way to do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting strings in PHP and get last part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030779/splitting-strings-in-php-and-get-last-part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rest of the string - you can use the [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with a single argument.

```
$word = "google";
$start = substr($word, 0, 4);
$rest = substr($word, 4);
```

If you want to actually create an array of characters from a string, there is a [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function:

e.g

```
$input = "google";
$result = str_split($input); 
print_r($result);

// Which would print:
Array
(
    [0] => G
    [1] => o
    [2] => o
    [3] => g
    [4] => l
    [5] => e
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `str_split` function like:

```
$string = 'google';
$output = str_split($string, 4);
print_r($output);
```

you can check your desired output [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d85576772d3f4864d97f3d75b5c7ed198a3a686b)

for more details about [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your code:

```
substr($word, 4);
```