# Replace after last occurence of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a scenario that i have to replace  after the last point must be replaced with asterisks for the IP address.

```
Wrong example: 123.456.789
Correct example: 123.456.***
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `strlen`, `str_repeat`, `strrpos` already invented

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030779/splitting-strings-in-php-and-get-last-part

Comment: echo preg_replace('/(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d/', '*', "123.456.789");

Comment: There is tons of options how you could to by regex. [See this demo for the first 5 I could think of](https://tio.run/##jdHLSsQwFAbgfZ/iWArTlCGlc/GCDt05SjcFt0GJzbENU5KQpoIw714TGXQWVVwmHL4//4npzDTdlfVDHUXJ4CzsIC5Wa7rZXtKr65v4NoryHApKYBykaoEr0MZJrXgPDTdutAit1aOJsOk0GIvti0XT8wbTRZ7SjFFSMpEvlhAnRRYvIaQQoBAzddJXPzoYPUgn3xF6rQ@8Qy5mYSbScsdElpAved5dn7kKW/5P98K7/tV/wBsPDwdpTLANtw70G7gOwU@Gq9cPSLOn6rEmaXZPZoPCYs5mjqcVzedtv4uwCpwGiwM6/xUC2D6cG62cVCPOV9r7Ss@EiWPIZNXvSdP0CQ) and please always show what you tried and include in question!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip  = "XXX.XXX.XXX";
$parts = explode(".", $ip);
if(count($parts) >= 2){
    $result = $parts[0].".".$parts[1]."."."***";
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

> explode() can be used

```
$a = '123.456.789';
$b = explode('.', $a);
print_r(str_replace(end($b), '***', $b));
```