# PHP list+explode VS substr+strpos - what is more efficient?

Tags: php, string, extract

Sample text:

```
$text = 'Administration\Controller\UserController::Save';
```

Task - extract everything before ::

Option 1:

```
list($module) = explode('::',$text);
```

Option 2:

```
$module = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, '::');
```

Which option is more efficient?

Comment: Test it, takes less time than to ask here.

Comment: what do you think which should be explode returns array while substr return portion of a string

Comment: Test it and share results ;)

Comment: It does not matter. Both will be quick enough. I prefer `explode`, but most people will say that `substr` is more effective.

Comment: working on small amount of data then preformation factor can be nigable

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: Good article for micro-optimization :) I've always used the explode method because I think its easier to read - and developer's time is more expensive than machine time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran a test and seems like the first solution is faster.
Here is the code for testing it:

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

function solution1($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
        list($module) = explode('::',$text);
}

function solution2($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
        $module = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, '::'));
}

$text = 'Administration\Controller\UserController::Save';

$time_start = microtime_float();

solution1($text);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did solution1 in $time seconds.\n";

$time_start = microtime_float();

solution2($text);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did solution2 in $time seconds.\n";
```

Test 1:
Did solution1 in 0.19701099395752 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.38502216339111 seconds.

Test 2:
Did solution1 in 0.1990110874176 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.37402105331421 seconds.

Test 3:
Did solution1 in 0.19801092147827 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.37002205848694 seconds.

Comment: You should provide the results :)

Comment: Test 1:
Did solution1 in 0.19701099395752 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.38502216339111 seconds.


Test 2:
Did solution1 in 0.1990110874176 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.37402105331421 seconds.


Test 3:
Did solution1 in 0.19801092147827 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.37002205848694 seconds.
 It is enough? :P

Comment: Yep awesome! Very interesting results

Comment: I'm surprised! I'd have expected Option2 to be faster, but I guess thinking about it Option2 iterates over the string twice. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: My own results:
c:\portal>php explode_vs_substr.php
Did solution1 in 0.0068480968475342 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.0088989734649658 seconds.

Comment: My own results are mixed: manually running the script several times, I'm getting mixed results - but in majority Option 1 is slower but a small margin... I guess the conclusion is - it doesn't matter which you use on non-performance critical systems

Comment: @KatyaS Linus Torvalds [about performance](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds#2008): "... performance almost *always* matters."

Comment: Performance difference between the two I believe is negligible and will vary depending on server configuration and application load. See all currently supported PHP versions:  https://3v4l.org/KPMu2#output

Comment: PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu: `Did solution1 in 0.01142 seconds.` and `Did solution2 in 0.00609 seconds.`

Comment: Actually had better result on solution 2 with 10000x same test on generated email address and split on "@".  You can find code here :  https://gist.github.com/MattLoyeD/12cf730a8cdce8af460aa122f25876ab

It seems to be depending on certain algorithm you need to implement, running it on a huge sum of data on 7.2 & 7.4 clearly makes second solution more efficient in email case.

Answer (score 9):

`substr+strpos` will be faster and take less cpu time and use less memeroy.

Let's find out the answer from php soruce code.

`explode` first:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(explode) 
{ 
    // other codes

    array_init(return_value); 

    if (str_len == 0) { 
        if (limit >= 0) { 
            add_next_index_stringl(return_value, "", sizeof("") - 1, 1); 
        } 
        return; 
    } 


    // other code
    if (limit > 1) { 
        php_explode(&zdelim, &zstr, return_value, limit); 
    } else if (limit < 0) { 
        php_explode_negative_limit(&zdelim, &zstr, return_value, limit); 
    } else { 
        add_index_stringl(return_value, 0, str, str_len, 1); 
    } 
}


PHPAPI void php_explode(zval *delim, zval *str, zval *return_value, long limit)
{
    char *p1, *p2, *endp;

    endp = Z_STRVAL_P(str) + Z_STRLEN_P(str);

    p1 = Z_STRVAL_P(str);
    p2 = php_memnstr(Z_STRVAL_P(str), Z_STRVAL_P(delim), Z_STRLEN_P(delim), endp);

    if (p2 == NULL) {
        add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, Z_STRLEN_P(str), 1);
    } else {
        do { 
            add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, p2 - p1, 1);
            p1 = p2 + Z_STRLEN_P(delim);
        } while ((p2 = php_memnstr(p1, Z_STRVAL_P(delim), Z_STRLEN_P(delim), endp)) != NULL &&
                 --limit > 1);

        if (p1 <= endp)
            add_next_index_stringl(return_value, p1, endp-p1, 1);
    }    
}
```

`explode` will call `php_memnstr` multiple times and `add_next_index_stringl` multiple times which will operate `the result list`.

Now `strpos`:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(strpos)
{
    zval *needle;
    char *haystack;
    char *found = NULL;
    char  needle_char[2];
    long  offset = 0;
    int   haystack_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sz|l", &haystack, &haystack_len, &needle, &offset) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (offset < 0 || offset > haystack_len) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Offset not contained in string");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (Z_TYPE_P(needle) == IS_STRING) {
        if (!Z_STRLEN_P(needle)) {
            php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Empty needle");
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }

        found = php_memnstr(haystack + offset,
                            Z_STRVAL_P(needle),
                            Z_STRLEN_P(needle),
                            haystack + haystack_len);
    } else {
        if (php_needle_char(needle, needle_char TSRMLS_CC) != SUCCESS) {
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
        needle_char[1] = 0;

        found = php_memnstr(haystack + offset,
                            needle_char,
                            1,
                            haystack + haystack_len);
    }

    if (found) {
        RETURN_LONG(found - haystack);
    } else {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}

PHP_FUNCTION(substr)
{
    // other code about postion
    RETURN_STRINGL(str + f, l, 1);
}
```

It calls `php_memnstr` only one time, and `substr` operates the input string in memery, return the sub one.

Comment: pretty valid for me ... if you have a string like 'a#b' and you want to split it, substr+strpos is faster. At least for me. For 1000000 operations the explode is .02 of a second slower! The "explode" function is made just for that, so I think i will use it. Is the code is cleaner. No time to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 7):

On my system:

```
~/pb$ uname -a && php -v
Linux hostname 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
PHP 5.4.19-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Aug 27 2013 00:42:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
    with XCache Cacher v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
```

I have results:

```
~/pb$ ./test ListVsSubstr
[============================================================>] 1000 u | 8134 u/s | Est: 0.0 s | Mem: 335.74 KB | Max: 357.96 KB
[============================================================>] 1000 u | 7808 u/s | Est: 0.0 s | Mem: 336.14 KB | Max: 357.96 KB
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance 
list+explode    1000            0.044890 sec    +0.00%
substr+strpos   1000            0.052825 sec    -17.68%
```

Test code here: [link](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/ListVsSubstr.php).
From time to time results slightly different, but `list+explode` is always faster more than 15%.

Different systems and PHP versions may have different results. You must check it by yourself and for sure in environment configuration identical to your production.

Comment: Nice set of tests! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Tested: explode with limit (solution3)
Tested: preg_match

note:
10000 is not enough for me, so I run with 10 000 000 x 3

```
<?php
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

function solution1($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
        list($module) = explode('::',$text);
}

function solution2($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
        $module = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, '::'));
}

function solution3($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
        list($module) = explode('::',$text, 2);
}

function solution4($text)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
        preg_match('/^(.*)::/', $text, $m) && $module = $m[1];

}

$text = 'Administration\Controller\UserController::Save';

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $time_start = microtime_float();

    solution1($text);

    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo "Did solution1 in $time seconds.\n";

    $time_start = microtime_float();

    solution2($text);

    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo "Did solution2 in $time seconds.\n";

    $time_start = microtime_float();

    solution3($text);

    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo "Did solution3 in $time seconds.\n";
}
```

And the results are:

```
Did solution1 in 6.4486601352692 seconds.
Did solution2 in 9.4331159591675 seconds.
Did solution3 in 6.6791591644287 seconds.
Did solution4 in 9.3652379512787 seconds.

Did solution1 in 7.1072399616241 seconds.
Did solution2 in 10.755952835083 seconds.
Did solution3 in 7.5958750247955 seconds.
Did solution4 in 9.4377269744873 seconds.

Did solution1 in 7.4207429885864 seconds.
Did solution2 in 10.894104003906 seconds.
Did solution3 in 7.701789855957 seconds.
Did solution4 in 9.5081558227539 seconds.
```

The solution3 is take longer than the solution1!

ran on cli, 100% cpu usage on 1 thread

Comment: I ran these tests locally, and when the delimiter is in the haystack multiple times (i.e. exploding `$text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';` with delimiter `' '`) then `solution3` is considerably faster than `solution1`.

Comment: Solution 2 will be significantly faster when considering more delimiters in the target string (the above text). It will also use less memory as mentioned in other answers. `Did solution1 in 2.9455399513245 seconds.
Did solution2 in 0.7404088973999 seconds.
Did solution3 in 1.1065330505371 seconds.` PHP 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Using the `time` command on Linux. The first one measured in at `0m0.024s` and the second at `0m0.011s`.

The second one appears to be faster. I ran it multiple times and the result (bar one time) seemed to be the same.

EDIT: As suggested, the other user said to run it in a loop of 5000. That completed with the same results.

Comment: 0.024s and 0.011s? Single command? I am getting 1000 in 0.012.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: what are those times? 24ms took what exactly?

Comment: I tried to make it as clear as possible. I used `time php file.php` and the first one is in reference to `list/explode` and the second `strpos`

Comment: I think it's more down to the fact that that's the time it takes PHP to spin up and the time each one takes is so insignificant, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

efficient ? if you mean by execution time. then run each in a loop multiple (1000) time and check the execution time.

Comment: I'm posting the question for the purpose of knowledge sharing. If you are wanting to be helpful, please provide your machine spec and test results